# Upgrade of nvidia graphics adapter fails on Lucid Lynx, low resolution only, no driver?

Tags: 10.04, nvidia, upgrade, graphics

I run two Ubuntu distros (& two MS systems) on the same hardware.

-Computer- 
 Intel Core 2 Quad CPU @ 2.66GHz; 8192MB; LGA 775 NVIDIA nForce 780i SLI FTW

I recently upgraded the graphics adapter from nvidia GTX260 to GTX 560 Ti/PCI/SSE2.

I did this by dropping the nvidia proprietary drivers before the hardware change.

The 10.10 Maverick Ubuntu worked well, but the 10.04 Lucid failed with a message saying no nvidia drivers found and suggested checking logs.  The 10.10 was a clean install, the 10.04 was an upgrade.

The broken Lucid system will run in reduce graphics mode.

Graphics is far outside my ken, so I could use some help or advice.

Note the mainboard uses an nvidia chipset (780i)

From kern.log:

```
    ⋯
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.135780] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.135788] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.203759] EXT3 FS on sdb1, internal journal
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.491117] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AAZA] enabled at IRQ 20
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.491122] HDA Intel 0000:00:0f.1: PCI INT B -> Link[AAZA] -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.491124] hda_intel: Disable MSI for Nvidia chipset
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.491237] HDA Intel 0000:00:0f.1: setting latency timer to 64
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692721] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AXV5] enabled at IRQ 16
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692725]   alloc irq_desc for 16 on node -1
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692727]   alloc kstat_irqs on node -1
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692732] nvidia 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> Link[AXV5] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692739] nvidia 0000:03:00.0: setting latency timer to 64
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692743] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:03:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692774] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 03:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1200) installed
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692775] NVRM: in this system is not supported by the 195.36.24 NVIDIA Linux
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692776] NVRM: graphics driver release.  Please see 'Appendix A -
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692777] NVRM: Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's README,
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692777] NVRM: available on the Linux graphics driver download page at
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692778] NVRM: www.nvidia.com.
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692784] nvidia: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -1
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692873] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
    Feb 14 16:55:56 worksta64 kernel: [   41.692875] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
    ⋯
```

From syslog/messages:

```
    ⋯
    Feb 14 16:33:32 worksta64 kernel: [  667.982856] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
    Feb 14 16:33:32 worksta64 kernel: [  667.982860] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742313] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [AXV5] enabled at IRQ 16
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742324] nvidia 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> Link[AXV5] -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742335] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:03:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742432] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 03:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1200) installed
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742433] NVRM: in this system is not supported by the 195.36.24 NVIDIA Linux
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742434] NVRM: graphics driver release.  Please see 'Appendix A -
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742435] NVRM: Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's README,
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742436] NVRM: available on the Linux graphics driver download page at
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742436] NVRM: www.nvidia.com.
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742443] nvidia: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -1
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742463] NVRM: The NVIDIA probe routine failed for 1 device(s).
    Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742464] NVRM: None of the NVIDIA graphics adapters were initialized!
    ⋯
```

From Xorg.failsafe.log (selected):

```
⋯
(II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
(II) NVIDIA GLX Module  195.36.24  Thu Apr 22 19:52:00 PDT 2010
(II) Loading extension GLX
⋯
(II) VESA(0): initializing int10
(II) VESA(0): Bad V_BIOS checksum
(II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
(II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 14336 kB
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: NVIDIA
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 112.36
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: GF104B Board - 10400050
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Chip Rev   
(II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
(==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
(==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
(==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
(II) Loading sub module "ddc"
(II) LoadModule: "ddc"
(II) Module "ddc" already built-in
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level 2
(II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 1 sec.
⋯
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
⋯
```

From apt history.log:

```
⋯
Start-Date: 2012-02-14  16:15:57
Upgrade: libldap-2.4-2 (2.4.21-0ubuntu5.6, 2.4.21-0ubuntu5.7), base-files (5.0.0ubuntu20.10.04.4, 5.0.0ubuntu20.10.04.5), php5 (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11, 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14), libapache2-mod-php5 (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11, 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14), php5-gd (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11, 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14), firefox-branding (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), firefox (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), atop (1.23-1, 1.23-1+squeeze1build0.10.04.1), libssl-dev (0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.6, 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.8), firefox-3.0-gnome-support (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), firefox-locale-en (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), libservlet2.5-java (6.0.24-2ubuntu1.9, 6.0.24-2ubuntu1.10), boot-sav (3.16-0ppa4~lucid, 3.17-0ppa2~lucid), firefox-3.0 (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), firefox-3.5 (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), libssl0.9.8 (0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.6, 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.8), media-player-info (12-1~lucid1, 16-1~lucid1), openssl (0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.6, 0.9.8k-7ubuntu8.8), php5-mysql (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11, 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14), php5-common (5.3.2-1ubuntu4.11, 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14), firefox-gnome-support (10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.2, 10.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.10.04.1), libldap2-dev (2.4.21-0ubuntu5.6, 2.4.21-0ubuntu5.7)
End-Date: 2012-02-14  16:18:49
⋯
Start-Date: 2012-02-14  16:39:35
Purge: nvidia-173-dev (173.14.22-0ubuntu11), nvidia-173 (173.14.22-0ubuntu11), nvidia-current (195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.1), nvidia-glx-173-dev (173.14.22-0ubuntu11), nvidia-173-kernel-source (173.14.22-0ubuntu11), nvidia-glx-173 (173.14.22-0ubuntu11), nvidia-settings (195.36.08-0ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2012-02-14  16:41:35
⋯
Start-Date: 2012-02-14  16:42:06
End-Date: 2012-02-14  16:42:15
⋯
Start-Date: 2012-02-14  16:46:19
Install: nvidia-current (195.36.24-0ubuntu1~10.04.1), nvidia-settings (195.36.08-0ubuntu2)
End-Date: 2012-02-14  16:47:56
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742432] NVRM: The NVIDIA GPU 03:00.0 (PCI ID: 10de:1200) installed
Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742433] NVRM: in this system is not supported by the 195.36.24 NVIDIA Linux
Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742434] NVRM: graphics driver release.  Please see 'Appendix A -
Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742435] NVRM: Supported NVIDIA GPU Products' in this release's README,
Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742436] NVRM: available on the Linux graphics driver download page at
Feb 14 16:33:33 worksta64 kernel: [  668.742436] NVRM: www.nvidia.com.
```

`sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-settings`

`sudo reboot`

Download the proprietary drivers from Nvida (It's the GeForce 500 series). The version of the driver on their site is 295.20. The version of the drivers from the repos is 195.36 and doesn't support your card.

I believe you have to `chmod +x` the .run file then run it - it's been years since I've done this (I've been running on an 8M Intel i810 for almost 4 years now...)

For what it's worth, the version in the Oneiric repos is 280.13

Comment: Confusing to me is why nvidia-current works on 10.10 maverick but not 10.04 maverick?  Is nvidia-current different for different releases?  295.20-0ubuntu1~maverick~xup1 is working on 10.10 maverick for this system...

Comment: Yes, different repositories have different versions. For example, Qemu 1.0 is not available in the Oneiric repositories, but it is available in the Precise repositories.

Comment: Right - I just booted lucid uses 195.36 like you said.  I thought lucid was still supported by Ubuntu but I guess not.  Thanks!

Comment: I was curious why you were using Maverick of all versions lol. It's generally recommended to upgrade each new version for home users. I usually wait about a month and a half in case there are any killer bugs so they can get ironed out. The term "Support" only applies to paid Canonical support for businesses running Ubuntu. There's really no incentive  for a home user to stay on an LTS.------- By the way, did you get it working yet?

Comment: Why 10.04? I have a bunch of heavy duty stuff that I do not care to nurse though a release upgrade⋯I'm too old and grumpy for that. I have two mythbuntu HTPCs that are 10.10, which is why I use Lucid.

Comment: It's been quite a while since I manually installed nvidia graphic drivers.  I went to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual and followed those instruction.  It worked gloriously.  The version I installed was 295.20, the same as from ubuntu for lucid.  Please point your elbow at the ceiling and pat yourself on the back!